# Creating new columns in Pandas dataframe reading csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm reading a simple csv file and creating a pandas dataframe. The csv file can have 1 row or 2 rows or 10 rows.

If the csv file has 1 row then I want to create few columns and if it has <=2 rows, then create couple of new columns and if it has 10 rows, then I want to create 10 new columns.

After reading the csv, my sample dataframe looks like below.

```
df=pd.read_csv('/home/abc/myfile.csv',sep=',')
print(df)

id rate amount address  lb   ub  msa
1  2.50    100 abcde    30   90  101
                        10   20  102
                                 103
                                 104
                                 105
                                 106
                                 107
                                 108
                                 109
                                 110
```

Case 1)If the dataframe has only 1 record then I want to create new columns 'new_id', 'new_rate' & 'new_address' and assign the values from 'id', 'rate' and 'address' columns coming from the dataframe

```
Expected Output:

id rate amount address  lb   ub  msa new_id new_rate new_address
1  2.50    100 abcde    30   90  101  1      2.50    abcde
```

Case 2)If the dataframe has <=2 records then I want to create for the 1st record 'lb_1', 'ub_1' with values 30 and 90 and for the 2nd record 'lb_2' & 'ub_2' with values 10 & 20 coming from the dataframe

```
Expected Output:

if there is only 1 row:
id rate amount address  lb   ub  msa lb_1 ub_1 
1  2.50    100 abcde    30   90  101 30   90   


if there are 2 rows:

id rate amount address  lb   ub  msa lb_1 ub_1 lb_2 ub_2
1  2.50    100 abcde    30   90  101 30   90   10   20
                        10   20  102
```

Case 3)If the dataframe has 10 records then I want to create 10 new columns ie, msa_1,msa_2....msa_10 and assign the respective values msa_1=101, msa_2=102.......msa_10=110 for each row coming from the dataframe

```
Expected Output:

id rate amount address  lb   ub  msa msa_1 msa_2 msa_3 msa_4 msa_5 msa_6 msa_7 msa_8 msa_9 msa_10
1  2.50    100 abcde    30   90  101 101   102   103   104   105   106   107   108   109   110
                        10   20  102
                                 103
                                 104
                                 105
                                 106
                                 107
                                 108
                                 109
                                 110
```

I'm trying to write the code as below but for 2nd and 3rd case, I'm not sure how to do it and also if there is any better way to handle all the 3 cases, that would be great.
Appreciate if anyone can show me the best way to get it done. Thanks in advance

```
Case1:                  
if df.shape[0]==1:
    df.loc[(df.shape[0]==1), "new_id"] = df["id"]
    df.loc[(df.shape[0]==1),"new_rate"]= df["rate"]
    df.loc[(df.shape[0]==1),"new_address"]= df["address"]                


Case2:
if df.shape[0]<=2:
    for i in 1 to len(df.index)
          df.loc[df['lb_i']]=db['lb']
          df.loc[df['ub_i']]=df['ub']


Case3:
if df.shape[0]<=10:
    for i in 1 to len(df.index)
        df.loc[df['msa_i']]=df['msa']
```

Comment: Since the number of rows are small, could you put a test dataset for each case in your question? It would help people pick it up quickly and test their codes.

Comment: @hegdep: Thanks..added the expected outputs for all the 3 cases

Answer (score 0):

for case 2 and case 3, you can do something like this -

Case 2-

```
# case 2
df= pd.read_csv('test.txt')
lb_dict = { f'lb_{i}': value for i,value in enumerate(df['lb'].to_list(),start=1)}
lb_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lb_dict, orient='index').transpose()
ub_dict = { f'ub_{i}': value for i,value in enumerate(df['ub'].to_list(),start=1)}
ub_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ub_dict, orient='index').transpose()

final_df = pd.concat([df,lb_df,ub_df],axis =1)
print(final_df)
```

**output-**

|  | id | rate | amount | address | lb | ub | msa | lb_1 | lb_2 | ub_1 | ub_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 2.5 | 100.0 | abcde | 30 | 90 | 101 | 30.0 | 10.0 | 90.0 | 20.0 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 10 | 20 | 102 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

For case 3 -

```
# case 3
df= pd.read_csv('test.txt')
msa_dict = { f'msa_{i}': value for i,value in enumerate(df['msa'].to_list(),start=1)}
msa_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(msa_dict, orient='index').transpose()
pd.concat([df,msa_df],axis =1)
```

**Output -**

|  | id | rate | amount | address | lb | ub | msa | msa_1 | msa_2 | msa_3 | msa_4 | msa_5 | msa_6 | msa_7 | msa_8 | msa_9 | msa_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 2.5 | 100.0 | abcde | 30.0 | 90.0 | 101 | 101.0 | 102.0 | 103.0 | 104.0 | 105.0 | 106.0 | 107.0 | 108.0 | 109.0 | 110.0 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 10.0 | 20.0 | 102 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 103 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 104 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 105 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 106 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 6 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 107 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 7 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 108 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 8 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 109 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 9 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 110 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Solution -

I've just created a dictionary from the required column and then I concatenated it with the original dataframe column-wise.

Comment: Thanks @Nk03 for the solution and it looks good. My goal is to create these additional variables for all case1,2 and 3 in one place as static global variables and use them further down in this and next programs. So, wondering if there is any way that we can create all these variables without creating lb_df, ub_df and msa_df dataframes and concatenate all of them. It would be great if we can create all these variables without creating any dataframe, and if I can read all of these variables in this and next programs.